# Validate file size before upload - IE8+

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I want to validate the file size before upload on IE8+

I tried

[Validate File size before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909521/validate-file-size-before-upload)

But didn't work.

And I can't configure every IE browser to use the "ActiveXObject" (I saw that is one way for the solution).

What I should do?

Comment: Don't use/support IE9 or older?  Other than that, your only other option is to use Flash.

Comment: I can't, the default browser approved is IE8+, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ASP.NET `FileUpload` control you cannot use code to validate the size of a file and inform the user.

If you want a better user experience, then I suggest you investigate some open source solutions like the following:

1. Custom HTTP module

   [NeatUpload](http://neatupload.codeplex.com/) is a free option.
2. Silverlight/Flash option

   [SWFUpload](https://github.com/WordPress/secure-swfupload) is a free option.
3. Asynchronous chunking option

   [RadAsyncUpload - Telerik's ASP.NET AsyncUpload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) is a pay option, check website for pricing.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="file">Filename:</label>
   <input type="file" name="file" id="myFile"><br>
</form>


<script>
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {
alert(this.files[0].size);
});
</script>
```