# Index was out of range when uploading files and form entry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, webmatrix

I got this "uploading file" code here taken from another site (because I'm too stupid to create one by myself) and I tryed to modify it by adding form entries.

```
@{ 
int id = 0;
var fileName = "";
var fileMime = "";

if (IsPost) {
    var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
    fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
    if(fileName != String.Empty)
    {
        fileMime = uploadedFile.ContentType;
        var fileStream = uploadedFile.InputStream;
        var fileLength = uploadedFile.ContentLength;

        byte[] fileContent = new byte[fileLength];
        fileStream.Read(fileContent, 0, fileLength);
        var No = Request.Form["No"];
        var Rue = Request.Form["Rue"];
        var CP = Request.Form["CP"];
        var Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
        var Etat = "En attente";
        var Commentaire = Request.Form["Commentaire"];
        var db = Database.Open("Empl2");
        var sql = "INSERT INTO Files (FileName, FileContent, MimeType, No, Rue, CP, Date, Commentaire, Etat) VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8)";
        db.Execute(sql, fileName, fileContent, fileMime, No, Rue, CP, Date, Commentaire, Etat);
        id = (int)db.GetLastInsertId();
    }
}
}
```

I got this message when I'm trying to use it

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

And here is the line:

```
var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
```

I tried a lot of things but so far nothing works.

There is also this code (uploadfile helper) in the html page...

```
@FileUpload.GetHtml(
    initialNumberOfFiles:1,
    allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
    includeFormTag:true,
    uploadText:"Envoyer")

@if (IsPost && fileName != String.Empty) {
    <span>Déclaration émise!</span><br/>
    if(fileMime.StartsWith("image")){
        <img src="Download.cshtml?Id=@id" alt="" />
    }
    else {
        <a href="Download.cshtml?Id=@id">Cliquez ici</a>
    }
}
```

Here is the site where I got the code... As I said, the picture alone is uploading with success... I just want to add a few informations with the picture

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/148/Save-And-Retrieve-Files-From-a-Sql-Server-CE-Database-with-WebMatrix

Comment: Why don't you handle this in the controller? I'm not understand where you get to this code. If you use a ViewModel to create the architecture for the form fields you will need you can follow this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909521/validate-file-size-before-upload/16086008#16086008 It will allow you to upload a file much easier. Everything you are trying to do in your code should be done in a controller, not a view.

Comment: in your view use `form` having enctype = `multipart` , explained clearly here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0

Comment: Arindam Nayak you were right. Can you post it as answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the main reason why it wasn't working was because of the OS of the phone my users had. Old OS 5 on Blackberry was known to have problems performing the upload of image on their browser =(

Thank you